# Remove duplicated entries from SuperTable related entries

Tags: relations, array, plugin-supertable

Anyone able to assist me with removing duplicates in this example?
So I have a related entries (cables) setup in a SuperTable. Some of these entries are duplicated across different rows. So a cable might be related to the first row in the SuperTable and also row3 and row4.

I want to be able to run through all these cables in any SuperTable row and output the entries just once not duplicated.
So as an example a basic SuperTable setup like this;

```
{% for row in entry.tests %}
    {% for cable in row.cables %}
        {{ cable.title }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

would output this;
BS 7211
BS EN 50525
BS 6724
BS 8573
BS 7835
BS 7629-1
BS 8436
BS 5467
BS 6724
BS 7846
BS 6622
BS 7835

I want to essentially loop through and only display the related entry once. As you can see from the example some entries are duplicated (e.g BS 6724)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a "filtered" array, containing the unique cables, and then loop through that.

For example:

```
{# Build the "filtered" array of cables #}
{% set filteredCables = [] %}

{% for row in entry.tests %}
    {% for cable in row.cables %}
        {% if cable.title not in filteredCables %}
            {% set filteredCables = filteredCables|merge([cable.title]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{# Output the unique cables #}
{% for cable in filteredCables %}
    {{ cable }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @StephenLewis - I had actually tried this as I picked it up from another stack exchange post. However, I keep hitting them same error; Variable "filteredCables" does not exist.

I have tried to set the {% set filteredCables = [] %} before I then set it in the loop but it still seems to output all the cables (duplicates) and not a filtered list. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the variable does not exist error, you could do this: `{% set filteredCables = filteredCables|default([])merge([cable]) %}`. As for it not outputting a filtered list, have you tried just adding the titles? For example: `{% if cable.title not in filteredCables %}{% set filteredCables = filteredCables|default([])|merge([cable]) %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks Stephen - the problem was solved by setting cable.title. I had to add an empty variable at the start outside the loop too {% set filteredCables = [] %}. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I've updated the answer to use the cable title.